# ¿Como puedo hacer que una función en oracle sql devuelva dos valores?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, function

Necesito que una función de oracle sql devuelva dos valores.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes hacer -por ahora- algo así como
(a,b) = funcion(a1,b1,c1)

Pero puedes usar funciones que modifican el valor de los parametros de entrada.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_ejemplo_salida(param_a text, 
    OUT param_salida_b text, OUT param_salida_c text)
   AS
$$
BEGIN
    param_salida_b := 'Hola';
    param_salida_c := 'Mundo';
END;
    $$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```